# How to change axis tick label size for dotchart

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a simple dotchart with dotchart() and increase both the x-axis label and x-axis tick label size.

For base graphics I found that I should use cex.axis or cex.axes but neither are working for dotchart(). I know it can be done because if I just put cex = 3 everything increases in size, including the tick labels.

Am I having difficulty because of differences between plot() and dotchart()?

```
dotchart(p$Turb, xlab = "Turb", cex.lab = 3, cex.axis = 3)
```

```
dotchart(p$Turb, xlab = "Turb", cex.lab = 3, cex.axes = 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw the `dotchart` without an x axis, then add one on with whatever parameters you like:

```r
dotchart(1:10, xlab = 'Turb', xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, 1:10, cex.axis = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks Allan.